# Proper syntax for iron-router's Router.route?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have the following code for my iron-router signOut route in a Meteor JS app. I am trying to convert the deprecated Router.map to the new Router.route syntax but having difficulty getting the onBeforeAction and onAfterAction to work. What is the proper Router.route syntax for the following code block?

```
Router.map(function () {

  // sign-out the user then redirect them to the home page
  this.route('signOut', {
    path: '/sign-out',
    onBeforeAction: function () {
      if (Meteor.userId()) {
        Meteor.logout()
      }
      this.next();
    },
    onAfterAction: function () {
      this.redirect('/');
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Router.route('/sign-out', function() {
//here you put things you wanna render, it's empty since you just want to logout and redirect
}, {
    name: 'signOut',
    onBeforeAction: function () {
      if (Meteor.userId()) {
        Meteor.logout()
      }
      this.next();
    },
    onAfterAction: function () {
      Router.go('/');
    }
});
```

And I think you should add waitOn function, cause there might be no Meteor.user() object at first if not subscribed earlier